# Kali Linux 2020.1, how to add keyboard layout menu in XFCE?

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, keyboard-layout

When I was changing keyboard layouts in Ubuntu, a visual menu was appearing and I could see the keyboard layouts like this:

[image: keyboard layout menu]

But there is not any visual menu of keyboard layouts on Kali 2020.1.

Is there any way to add same menu on Kali 2020.1?

Answer (score 0):

Xfce proposes a different visual aid to the keyboard layouts than the current version of GNOME.

You can add "Keyboard Layouts" widget to your Xfce Panel. With it you see a country flag in the panel, which corresponds to your currently active keyboard layout. You can also click on the widget to get the list of available layouts and click on any of the layouts to switch to that layout.

The widget is not added to the Xfce Panel in Kali Linux by default. To add it, right-click on your panel. Then, in the context menu, choose "Panel" → "+ Add New Items…" Next, in the "Add New Items" dialogue, search for "Keyboard Layouts", select the option "Keyboard Layouts", and click "+ Add" button.

Tested in Kali Linux 2021.3. More information about multiple keyboard layouts management in Xfce is availbale at their site: https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin/start

[image: A screenshot of the flag-like widget with its menu of available layouts open.][image: Navigation to "Add New Item" menu option.][image: "Add New Item" dialogue.]

Answer (score 0):

***Roman Riabenko answered Oct 10, 2021 at 20:28***
*...right-click on your panel. Then, in the context menu, choose "Panel" → "+ Add New Items…" Next, in the "Add New Items" dialogue, search for "Keyboard Layouts", select the option "Keyboard Layouts", and click "+ Add" button.*

Adding on to the above.
Then right-click on the flag in the panel → "Keyboard settings" → "Layout" tab → switch off "Use system defaults" → press "Add" in the "Keboard layout" section and add the language you need.

In the "Change layout section" you may choose the way to switch languages (Alt + Shift, Ctrl + Shift etc.)

[image]

Comment: If you are building on (i.e., adding to, or clarifying) somebody else’s answer, you should say so explicitly, link to the other answer and mention the author’s name.  It may be best to quote enough of the existing answer (being sure to *identify* it as a quote) so that your answer continues to make sense if the other answer ever disappears.

Answer (score -2):

The ability to display keyboard layouts is built into Gnome. Gnome is usually the default for xfce.
The package that allows command line display of keyboard layouts is `gkbd-capplet` in Debian (and consequently Kali).

So:

```
sudo apt-get install gkbd-capplet
```

will install such capability in gnome.

And:

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l us
```

Will display the keyboard layout for the US language. And `am`, for example, for Armenian.

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Keyboard_layouts_for_non-Latin_alphabetic_scripts) might help to find the language names an two letters ID.

Comment: Xfce is a desktop environment, like gnome is. So gnome can't be "the default for Xfce", they are two different things in the same category.